# Problema no código php pra listar os dados gravados no banco de dados (iniciante)

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Coloquei a imagem do bb e os códigos php abaixo para que alguém possa me ajudar, pois não consigo encontrar solução.

***Erro:***

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in D:\ANALISE E DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMAS\XAMPP INSTALADO\htdocs\teste\lista.php on line 22
```

[image: Bando de dados com uma tabela e os ítens no phpmyadmin.]
***Código de conexão com bb:***

```
<?php

        $conexao=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
?>
```

***Código de gravação no bb:***

```
<?php
    include("conecta.php");

    $recnome=$_GET["nome"];
    $recemail=$_GET["email"];
    $recmensagem=$_GET["mensagem"];

    mysqli_query(conexao, "insert into dados (nome, email, mensagem) values ('recnome', 'recemail', 'recmensagem')");
    //Insira na minha tabela "dados", no campo "nome", o valor de "recnome" e assim sucessivamente...

    header("location:lista.php");

?>
```

***código de listagem:***

```
<?php   
    include("conecta.php"); //Aqui estou me conectando ao banco de dados.
    $seleciona=mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from dados order by id desc");//Selecione tudo da tabela "dados" e coloque em ordem decescente.
        while($campo=mysqli_fetch_array($seleciona)){?> <!-- Laço de repetição-->
        <!--Enquanto a minha variável campo recebe cada item da matriz array "seleciona"-->
            <tr>
                <td><?=$campo["nome"]?></td>
                <td><?=$campo["email"]?></td>
                <td><?=$campo["mensagem"]?></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="editar.php?editaid=<?=$campo["id"]?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#" onclick="verifica(<?=$campo["id"]?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
            </tr>

        <?php   }?>
```

Comment: Não é bem visto por aqui postar a imagem da definição da tabela. Na imagem me parece que a tabela se chama "teste" mas em seu comando insert você informa a tabela "dados". Idem no select.

Comment: Certo. Peço desculpas pela imagem. Não sabia. Sou novo. Muito obrigado. Irei corrigir agora mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você está realizando o insert na tabela **dados**, sendo que o nome da tabela que você possui é **teste**.

A função mysqli_query retorna um objeto do tipo mysqli_result em caso de sucesso é false em casa de falha.

A função mysqli_fetch_array espera receber como parâmetro o objeto mysqli_result.

Como o SQL esta incorreto, o tipo de parâmetro errado está sendo passado para mysqli_fetch_array e por isso o warning está sendo disparado.

A função mysqli_query retorna false em caso de erro

[mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

[mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Ótimo. Obrigado. Irei corrigir agora mesmo. Grato.